# AX12 dual motor index out of range

Tags: ros, ax12

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working through the ax12 smart arm tutorials on diamondback with ubuntu 10.4 as
soon as i start a dual motor controller i receive this error

```
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1301047084.826573] bad callback: <bound method JointPositionControllerDualAX12.process_motor_states of <joint_position_controller_dual_motor.JointPositionControllerDualAX12 instance at 0x8f0e06c>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/src/rospy/topics.py", line 563, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)
  File "/home/peter/ros/ua-ros-pkg/arrg/ua_controllers/ax12_controller_core/src/ax12_controller_core/joint_position_controller_dual_motor.py", line 146, in process_motor_states
    state = states[self.master_id]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This error just cycles continuously but the joint will move with commands

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9561/ax12-dual-motor-index-out-of-range/) by [Peter Heim](https://answers.ros.org/users/71/peter-heim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 215 on 2011-03-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-04-03**:
Or add it to your question with block quotes.

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-03-28**:
Can you put this on pastebin or somewhere that doesn't mangle the formatting?

**Comment by [Peter Heim](https://answers.ros.org/users/71/peter-heim/) on 2011-03-26**:
head_pan_controller:
controller:
package: ax12_controller_core
module: joint_position_controller
type: JointPositionControllerAX12
joint_name: head_pan_joint
joint_speed: 1.17
motor:
id: 7
init: 512
min: 0
max: 1024

head_tilt_controller:
controller:
package: ax12_controller_core
module: joint_position_controller
type: JointPositionControllerAX12
joint_name: head_tilt_joint
joint_speed: 1.17
motor:
id: 8
init: 512
min: 800
max: 300

pan_base_controller:
controller:
package: ax12_controller_core
module: joint_position_controller
type: JointPositionControllerAX12
joint_name: base_pan_joint
joint_speed: 1.17
motor:
id: 3
init: 512
min: 273
max: 751

shoulder_tilt_controller:
controller:
package: ax12_controller_core
module: joint_position_controller_dual_motor
type: JointPositionControllerDualAX12
joint_name: shoulder_tilt_joint
joint_speed: 1.17
motor_master:
id: 6
init: 512
min: 717
max: 126
motor_slave:
id: 2

elbow_tilt_controller:
controller:
package: ax12_controller_core
module: joint_position_controller
type: JointPositionControllerAX12
joint_name: elbow_tilt_joint
joint_speed: 1.17
motor:
id: 5
init: 512
min: 881
max: 126

wrist_rotate_controller:
controller:
package: ax12_controller_core
module: joint_position_controller
type: JointPositionControllerAX12
joint_name: wrist_rotate_joint
joint_speed: 1.17
motor:
id: 4
init: 512
min: 1023
max: 0

### **Comment by [Peter Heim](https://answers.ros.org/users/71/peter-heim/) on 2011-03-26**:
motor_statemotor_states:

```
timestamp: 1301225172.3
id: 2
goal: 172
position: 171
error: -1
speed: 0
load: 0.0
voltage: 12.7
temperature: 41
moving: False
```

- timestamp: 1301225172.31
  id: 3
  goal: 737
  position: 737
  error: 0
  speed: 0
  load: 0.0
  voltage: 13.0
  temperature: 41
  moving: False
- timestamp: 1301225172.31
  id: 4
  goal: 512
  position: 512
  error: 0
  speed: 0
  load: 0.0
  voltage: 12.7
  temperature: 42
  moving: False
- timestamp: 1301225172.31
  id: 5
  goal: 315
  position: 315
  error: 0
  speed: 0
  load: 0.0
  voltage: 12.7
  temperature: 41
  moving: False
- timestamp: 1301225172.32
  id: 6
  goal: 862
  position: 863
  error: 1
  speed: 4
  load: 0.0078125
  voltage: 12.6
  temperature: 41
  moving: False
- timestamp: 1301225172.32
  id: 7
  goal: 1023
  position: 1023
  error: 0
  speed: 0
  load: 0.0
  voltage: 13.0
  temperature: 40
  moving: False
- timestamp: 1301225172.33
  id: 8
  goal: 549
  position: 550
  error: 1
  speed: 4
  load: 0.0078125
  voltage: 12.7
  temperature: 42
  moving: False

---

^Cpeter@robot:~$

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2011-03-25**:
Can you post your controller configuration and output of rostopic echo /motor_states/ttyUSB0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This was a bug in the dual motor controller code, it is fixed as of revision 1303.

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2011-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2